# Compiling ES6 (ReactJS) code to work with IE >=9

Tags: laravel, reactjs, babeljs, laravel-mix

So I have been building an application in React JS and have been taking advantage of some of the syntax that ES6 provides such as:

- using let and const
- class components
- arrow functions (componentWillMount = () => {})
- constructorless state declaration (state = {someProperty: true})

I am running into some issues when compiling though. My code seems to work with most chromes as far as I can tell but the whole thing breaks down around IE9 or IE10. What is the proper way to set up my .babelrc file? (below is what I have right now)

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2016"],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Also bonus points to anyone who knows how to set this up for Laravel-mix as the components I have built live within a laravel 5.5 env. (here is how my webpack.mix.js file looks as of right now)

```
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/cross-brand-nav.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/FullWidthTabs.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/universal-nav.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .version()
    .combine([
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/moment/min/moment.min.js',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/admin.js'
    ], 'public/js/admin.js').version()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/bower_assets/components-font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss', 'public/css').version()
    .styles([
        'resources/assets/css/FullWidthTabs.css'
    ], 'public/css/pf.css')
    .styles([
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'resources/assets/bower_assets/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'
        ], 'public/css/admin.css').version();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://babeljs.io/repl/ to convert your code to work with whatever browser you want , it has lot of options for conversion , try that and if you have any question post it here we will help